# Installing lower version of GLIBC and running pyinstaller

Tags: python, ubuntu, glibc, pyinstaller

I'm trying to create an executable of a PyGTK application. But I'm getting Glibc version conflict while running the executable in client machines.(Since version of glibc(2.5) is lower in client machines than the version of glibc(2.13) where pyinstaller executable is created.)

So I wanted to know

Is it possible to install lower version of GLIBC separately in the machine where higher version of GLIBC is already running(Keeping multiple copies of GLIBC)?

And Is there any way we can tell pyinstaller to choose a version of GLIBC while creating an executable?

And if the above is possible then how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to install lower version of GLIBC separately in the machine where higher version of GLIBC is already running(Keeping multiple copies of GLIBC)?

Yes, it's possible (we do that every day). It's not entirely trivial, and you don't actually need to do *that* to solve your problem.

> And Is there any way we can tell pyinstaller to choose a version of GLIBC while creating an executable?

What you want is a Linux-to-(older)-Linux cross-compiler. GCC can be configured as such a cross-compiler. This is also not entirely trivial.

Some easier solutions are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8846364/50617).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Finally I installed glibc using a rpm package.