# Compile a Fortran program using an older version of glibc

Tags: ubuntu, glibc

I have written a program in Ubuntu 14.04LTS. When I copy this complied program to the server and run, it says that

> The version 'GLIBC_2.14' was not found".

I checked the version of the Ubuntu in the server, it is 10.04.4 LTS with the 2.11 version of `glibc`. Since I do not have the permission to update the system in the server, I wonder whether I can compile the program in my Ubuntu system using the 2.11 version of `glibc`?
I searched this problem almost everywhere, but can not find the solution. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder whether I can compile the program in my Ubuntu system using the 2.11 version of glibc

You can, but this is non-trivial. Some solutions are in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8846364/50617).