# Downgrade libc6 version

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, glibc, libc

`ldd --version` shows that I have Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1, and I need a version <= 2.24.
Tried to use `sudo apt-get install libc6==2.23-0ubuntu1` but it says this version cannot be found. I have searched on [Ubuntu packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=cosmic&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libc6&searchon=names) to find a version that suits my requirements but couldn't find anything.

Can anyone help to downgrade my libc6? I need my gcc to compile with GLIBC <= 2.24 for a plugin I'm making.

Comment: Why do you think an old version of glibc is required for building a GCC plugin?

Comment: @FlorianWeimer because of `version GLIBC_2.14 not found` error

Comment: But glibc 2.27 from Ubuntu has version GLIBC_2.14. Are you building on Ubuntu and deploying on something else (including an older version of Ubuntu)?

Comment: The latter. Client had a lower version of GLIBC so that I needed to downgrade. I ended up just using an ancient version of openSUSE to compile