# On Linux, ABI in ELF header set to Sys V, not Linux?

Tags: c, linux, unix, gcc, elf

Under Linux, when I compile the following program:

```
int main() {}
```

With gcc 4.7:

```
$ gcc test.c
```

And inspect the resulting executable with `readelf`:

```
$ readelf -h a.out
...
OS/ABI: UNIX - System V
...
```

It has the `EI_OSABI` byte in the ELF header set to `ELFOSABI_SYSV`, and not `ELFOSABI_LINUX`.

Does anyone know the history or reasoning behind this?  Naively, one might expect it to be set to Linux.

Further, what are the consequences of setting it to Linux?

Comment: Maybe partially related: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/2020961/1131467](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2020961/1131467)